# How to add printer to CUPS using Ghostscript hl7x0 driver?

Tags: cups, ghostscript

I run Arch Linux 64-bit and strongly prefer not to add multiarch support for 32-bit software, so I do not want to install the proprietary 32-bit driver for my Brother MFC-J4710DW printer. Research revealed that the printer should work with Ghostscript driver hl7x0. So, I installed package ghostscript and ran command "gs -h", which showed that driver hl7x0 is included.

However, I cannot find a way to select that driver when running CUPS - Add Printer. I have stopped and restarted the cupsd daemon, but I still cannot find how to select that driver. What do I need to do?

Comment: The Brother proprietary drivers would probably work fine. I have a Brother Multifunction too, and I use the 32 bit drivers. It's possible one could get hold of the source and compile a 64 bit version, but I never checked that. Though I use Debian, which it actually has packages for.

Comment: Yes, thanks Faheem, but like I said, I do not want multiarch on this system.